# 500 mV p-p noise in two stage photodiode amplifier output

Tags: amplifier, noise, photodiode, output

I have problem with power supply noise finding its way to op-amp output. Power line (+ and -) noise is 40 mV p-p. Is this due to poor pcb layout or poor filtering and what to do to make it better.

I need to use high first stage gain of around 1-3 Mohm and still maintain frequency response of ~200 kHz
Schematics:
[image: Schematics]

Board layout:
[image: Board layout]

Power supply noise:
[image: Power supply noise (+ and -)]

Output noise:
[image: Second stage output noise pulse_a]

Comment: So the reason for reverse-bias is to reduce the effective PD capacitance and increase frequency response to achieve 200 kHz peak bandwidth? If so, I'd like to see your calculations here. In detail. 1st stage design is ***everything***. It all happens there. The rest is just dealing with the fall-out. So I don't care about anything but the thinking behind the 1st stage.

Comment: how do you probe? dangling ground wire? That could give fake noise readings. But I think they are likely real because there is no suitable filtering on your rails to remove of kHz range noise. You need some series inductor and bulk electrolytic cap to meaningfully suppress ripple amplitude at kHz frequncies.

Comment: Yes dangling ground wire definitely makes some noise but as you said it is likely that most of this noise is real ripple. I'll try replacing the fuse with an inductor and adding 2.2 uF tantalum capacitors to power lines to see if I can further reduce power supply ripple.

Comment: About first stage design I have to admit that I really haven't made any exact calculations just checked that everything is about right. All the parasitic capacitances and inductances make it hard to calculate everything ecaxtly correctly and in the end you just have to test everything e.g. feedback capacitor value for stability. Will dig in more thoroughly to the first stage calculations though to have clear starting point for testing. And then make one pcb with first stage only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start by looking in this direction: -

[image]

Your power supply noise is less than 3 decades above your power supply filter cut-off point i.e. 160 Hz --> 1.6 kHz --> 16 kHz --> 160 kHz.

This means that the attenuation will be about 60 dB or maybe 56 dB (if I worked it out more accurately). A 123 kHz, 25 mV p-p signal on your power line becomes about 40 μV p-p on the photodiode cathode. I don't know what the capacitance is of the photodiode but it might be (say) 10 pF and, at 123 kHz, that is a reactance of 130 kΩ.

And, this does look like a problem because your feedback resistor is 6 MΩ and therefore your front-end amplifier is amplifying the 40 μV p-p into something like 2 mV p-p.

After this front-end you have another stage with a gain of 20 so now the noise is 40 mV p-p. I suspect that this is worth looking into because, if your photodiode is more like 100 pF then that becomes 400 mV p-p at the output (close to what your scope picture suggests).

Comment: I'll try decreasing the 160 Hz filter cut-off frequency and also will try grounding the cathode to get better idea where the noise is coming from. Thank you for the detailed calculations. It seems like the problem could come from here since the capacitance of the photodiode with 5 V reverse bias is ~65 pF.

Comment: @JesseHaataja with 65 pF it's a likely cause but, it's by no-means certain of being a single cause of your output noise.

Comment: Yes, this with poor power rail filtering are the first things I'll try to make better. I'll also try to use 9 V battery for biasing the photodiode.